# Webserver cannot be reached from outside, but updates are available and URLs are resolved

Tags: web-server, ubuntu-20.04

I'm having trouble with my web server. It cannot be reached from outside, and I don't know how to proceed.

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- ufw is not running

  - executing `ufw status` on the server yields `Status: inactive`
- `ping [public server IPv4]` from outside does not return anything
- `ping [server URL]` resolves to IPv6, but nothing is returned
- Ports are open

  - Running `nc -v [IPv4 of server] [PORT]` on the server gives `Connection to [...] succeeded!`
- When I run ping in the server's terminal with any URL, it gets resolved, but apparently nothing comes back.
- Pulling updates from the official sources works

  - `apt update` connects to all sources

Where should I go from here?

Comment: Please be more specific, provide the commands you used for testing and their output.

Comment: What Gerald said. Also when you say `it cannot be reached from outside`, explain what exactly do you mean. Error, timeout, something else?

Comment: Your router/modem, and maybe even your ISP, between your server and the open Internet likely has a firewall blocking incoming ports.  If this is the case, and you open a port, or ports, be prepared for immediate and continuous probing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use a public IPv4 (and are not seemingly NATing from a home router for instance) it's likely that the problem is linked to the network being blocked at some point.

The application `ufw` itself might not be active, but the underlying "real" firewall, `iptables` might have rules set.

Try

```
# iptables -S
# ip6tables -S
```

to list all rules.

If you are not directly connected to an ISP, check the router or whatever device your ISP may have given to you.

(Note: one of our servers, for instance says

```
  # ufw status
  Status: inactive
```

while ip[6]tables is actively running with many rules)